# in Jenkins, how to store Console output results to github?

Tags: jenkins

How to deploy test report back to github or to my local?
I have the connection from Github to Jenkins using webhook, and the connection from Jenkins to Github using Jenkins setting/Pipeline and add my repository.

The result of the test shows in the Jenkins/Console Output., how to get the result stored somewhere else (such as GithUb) or my local or some server, is there a setup for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here is one way.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Sample') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Somehitng 1"
                    echo "Something 2"
                    // Read the console log
                    def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
                    //Write the log to a file
                    writeFile(file: "Log_${BUILD_NUMBER}.txt", text: consoleLog, encoding: "UTF-8")
                    sh'''
                        git add *
                        git commit -m "Add console log"
                        git push
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```